# Is this right $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{kx^kn!}(x-1)^{n+k}=(e^{1-x}-1)\log x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is this right $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{kx^kn!}(x-1)^{n+k}=(e^{1-x}-1)\log x$$
I want to check it by using Wolfram but it seems there is no double sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just, assuming $\left|1-\frac{1}{x}\right|<1$:
$$\sum_{k,n\geq 1}\frac{1}{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^k\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(x-1)^n}{n!}=\log x\left(e^{1-x}-1\right). $$

Answer (score 1):

If $\left|\frac{x-1}{x}\right|<1$
  we have, using Taylor series $$\sum_{k\geq1}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{kx^{k}n!}\left(x-1\right)^{n+k}=-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{k}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n!}\left(1-x\right)^{n}=\left(e^{1-x}-1\right)\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Your summand can be written as $f_n(x)g_k(x)$ so the sum is simply $\sum_n f_n(x) \sum_k g_k(x)$.

Then they're pretty usual series.